# save checkpoint with Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have 3 folders for my CNN model which are `train_data, val_data, test_data.`

when I am training my model, I found that the accuracy may vary and sometimes the last epoch does not show the best accuracy. for example, last epoch accuracy is 71% but I found the better accuracy in the earlier epoch. I want to save the checkpoint of that epoch which has higher accuracy and then use that checkpoint to predict my model on `test_data`

I trained my model  on `train_data` and predicted  on `val_data` and save the checkpoint of the model like below:

```
    print("{} Saving checkpoint of model...". format(datetime.now()))
    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'model_epoch' + str(epoch) + '.ckpt')
    save_path = saver.save(session, checkpoint_path)
```

and before starting the `tf.Session()` I have this line:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

I want to know how can I save the best epoch which has higher accuracy and then use this checkpoint for my `test_data`?

Comment: By the way, seeing your code, you should not add '.ckpt' to your path as you are doing. You should only specify the directory.

Comment: A note: from what I understand, by doing this you are actually training on the validation data. The is no guarantee that it will perform better on test data.

Comment: @geometrikal, You are right. There is no guarantee that it performs well on my test data but the aim of validation set is to find the best hyperparameters for your model and then use those hyperparameters on the test data. that's why I want to save the best hyperparameters of my model and then use them on test

Comment: Out of interest, do you use learning rate decay? I have found that can both improve and stabilise accuracy.

Comment: I am using AdamOptimizer with fix learning rate

Comment: I also use Adam, but I found that by drop the learning rate by half when the loss is no longer decreasing, and repeating this drop a few times, the accuracy improves and stabilises.

Comment: Hey @nairouzmrabah, I have tried to fixed your code but I couldn't, I will be appreciated if you can help me to save the best epoch

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.train.Saver()` documentation describes the following:

```
saver.save(sess, 'my-model', global_step=0) ==> filename: 'my-model-0'
...
saver.save(sess, 'my-model', global_step=1000) ==> filename: 'my-model-1000'
```

Note that if you pass `global_step` to the saver you will generate checkpoint files that contain the global step number. I generally save checkpoints every X minutes and then come back and review the results and choose a checkpoint at the appropriate step value. If you're using tensorboard you'll find this intuitive since all your graphs can be displayed by global step as well.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver

Comment: Hey, If I set my number of epochs to 100 or more then I have to review the results for 100 epochs which, I think is wasting time. I need a way to save the best epoch automatically instead of reviewing all the results. Do you think is there any other way?

Comment: You can, of course, write code to analyze the results of each training step and optionally save a checkpoint. Do be aware that you are overfitting to your validation data with this procedure, so you should hold out a third set of test data to report final results on.

Comment: Hey, my aim of this project is to train my data based on train_set and val_set. Save the checkpoint for the best epoch and use the saved checkpoint for applying on test_set. is it the correct way? I mean, as I understand the goal of validation is to find the best hyperparameters for your model and used these hyperparameters on test_set

Comment: Correct, I was just making sure you were familiar with the practice, what you described is the standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CheckpointSaverListener](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointSaverListener).

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from sacred import Experiment

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

ex = Experiment('test-07-05-2018')    

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
checkpoint_path = "/tmp/checkpoints/"

class ExampleCheckpointSaverListener(CheckpointSaverListener):
    def begin(self):
       print('Starting the session.')
       self.prev_accuracy = 0
       self.acc = 0

   def after_save(self, session, global_step_value):
       print('Only keep this checkpoint if it is better than the previous one')
       self.acc = acc 
       if self.acc <  self.prev_accuracy :
            os.remove(tf.train.latest_checkpoint())
       else:
            self.prev_accuracy = self.acc

   def end(self, session, global_step_value):
       print('Done with the session.')

@ex.config
def my_config():
pass

@ex.automain
def main():
      #build the graph of vanilla multiclass logistic regression
      x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
      y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10]) 
      W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
      b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
      y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b) #
      loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(y_pred), reduction_indices=1))
      optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
      init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
      y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, dimension=1)
      y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y, dimension=1)
      correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_pred_cls, y_true_cls)
      accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
      saver = tf.train.Saver()
      listener = ExampleCheckpointSaverListener()
      saver_hook = tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir, listeners=[listener])
      with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(chief_only_hooks=[saver_hook]) as sess:
          sess.run(init)
          for epoch in range(25):
              avg_loss = 0.
              total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/100)
              # Loop over all batches
              for i in range(total_batch):
                  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
                  _, l, acc = sess.run([optimizer, loss, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
                  avg_loss += l / total_batch
                  saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path)
```

Comment: Do you have the example of the code which, explain how am I going to use this code? I think This class inherits from CheckpointSaverListener class. where is CheckpointSaverListener class? Thanks.

Comment: Please add explanation How should I use CheckpointSaverListener. I got confused

Comment: I wrote this code myself just to explain how to keep the checkpoint with the best accuracy and remove all the other ones. I thought it is straightforward. What is not clear?

Comment: You can find explanation right here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointSaverListener

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope you will find it easy to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the full code. I will get this error `name 'CheckpointSaverListener' is not defined` which there is a red line under this line `class ExampleCheckpointSaverListener(CheckpointSaverListener):`
for solving this error I added [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py] to my project and import  `CheckpointSaverListener`  from it but I got a different error and this time error is `Either every_secs or every_steps should be provided.`

Comment: I will fix the code later when I have some free time.

Comment: Hey, did you find some free time?

Comment: Hi, I m a little bit busy. I will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for the delay.